# Declare array of Integers

Tags: vba

I want to create an array of integers in VBA

I know that I can do using

```
Dim xyz() as Variant
xyz = Array(1,3,5,10,20,30,32, 45, 76, 89, 100, 34, 12, 0, 1, 100, 34, 45, 56, 67)
```

but I do not want to use variant data type and want xyz to be first declared as integer.
I also know how many elements are there in the array so that is not an issue.

One option is to do as shown below, but this is a very tedious and can take lot of time

```
Dim xyz(0 to 19) as Integer
xyz(0)=1
xyz(2)=3
xyz(3)=5
...
```

Is there a shorter way to achieve the objective.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Variant` type?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using `Array` in this scenario..?

Comment: I do see what is wrong with using `Integer` instead of `Long`, because `Integer` is a 16-bit type with range `-32768..+32767` and any value above or below that is going to overflow error. It is **highly recommended** to never use `Integer` and always use `Long` it it's place.

Comment: Array always return a variant data type, use of variant data Type is not a good practice and one should avoid if possible. Hence I am trying to make use of Integer but at the same time initialize my array elements with specific values.

Comment: @John, even if I use Long how would that solve the issue?

Comment: My values are going to be less than 5000 so I believe Integer data type is the right choice instead of Long data type.

Comment: @Alok As far as I know - Even if you declare as `Integer`, VBA will convert it to `Long` internally so there's no point using `Integer`. If you insist to have it as `Integer` array then, I think the easiest way is still to make it to a `Variant` array first, declare an `Integer` array of the same size as the `Variant` array, do a loop to assign the value and then `Erase` the `Variant` array.

Comment: `Array` is a function. Giving values to the array using `xyz = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)` is almost similar with `xyz(0) = 1: xyz(1) = 2: xyz(2) = 3: xyz(3) = 4`, in terms of effort. Usually, in the real life, such an array should be loaded by iteration. In order to experiment this possibility, try doing what @Raymond Wu suggested above. And using an `Integer` declaration **in VBA** does not bring any benefit, in terms of efficiency. That's why it is good to cultivate the habit of using `Long`. In this case, you will avoid problems in case of iterating through large ranges exceeding the Integer posib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two arrays, but why?
*Edit: see also comment of Raymond Wu*

```
 Sub tst()
    Dim xyz() As Integer, zyx As Variant, i As Long
        zyx = Array(1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 32, 45, 76, 89, 100, 34, 12, 0, 1, 100, 34, 45, 56, 67)
        ReDim xyz(LBound(zyx) To UBound(zyx))
            For i = LBound(xyz) To UBound(xyz)
                xyz(i) = zyx(i)
            Next
    End Sub
```